# Angularjs: Defining column at runtime in dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drop down that is getting binded to json object.

I want to define column name at runtime to which dropdown will be binded. Please help

Code Snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<div ng-controller="HelloController">

    <select ng-options="p.name for p in phones" ng-model="p.name"></select>

</div>


<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
    .controller("HelloController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.helloTo = {};
        $scope.selectedVal = "name";
        $scope.helloTo.title = "World, AngularJS";
        $scope.phones = [{
            'name': 'Nexus S',
            'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
            'age': 1
        }, {
            'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
            'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
            'age': 2
        }, {
            'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
            'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
            'age': 3
        }];

    });

</script>
```

I want to define something like below **$scope.selectedVal**

```
 <select ng-options="$scope.selectedVal for p in phones" ng-model="p.name"></select>
```

Comment: not sure but check if this works: <select ng-options="p[selectedVal] for p in phones" ng-model="p.name"></select>

Comment: @HarishR: Yes that works for me but what to define in ng-model?

Comment: <select ng-options="p[selectedVal] for p in phones" ng-model="selectedOption"></select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
     <select ng-options="p[selectedVal] for p in phones" ng-model="selectedOption"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following code.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <select ng-options="p.name for p in phones" ng-model="selectedValue"></select>
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.phones = [
        {
            'name': 'Nexus S',
            'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
            'age': 1
        }, 
        {
            'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
            'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
            'age': 2
        }, 
        {
            'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
            'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
            'age': 3
        }
    ];
    $scope.selectedValue = $scope.phones[0];
}
```

This is [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7483/) with your example.